# Insertar ItemArray en SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net

estoy intentando insertar registro por registro de excel a SQL, ya tengo cargado mi excel, lo recorro con un foreach de la siguiente manera:

```
SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection();
cnn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=Localhost;Initial Catalog=DevLiverpool_DB; Integrated Security = True";
cnn.Open();
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
                SqlCommand cmnd = new SqlCommand("insert into Ciudad_tb (Id_ciudaddestino, Ciudadestino) values (" + row.ItemArray[0].ToString() + ",'" + row.ItemArray[1].ToString() + "'", cnn);
                cmnd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

Pero me manda un error cerca de mi sintaxis, ya hice el debugg y estoy observando que así como lo hago el item array trae todos los datos y no solo el que quiero insertar, no se si me explique bien...
Saludos y gracias por la ayuda

Comment: ¿cuál es el mensaje de error exacto que te _manda_?

Answer (score 3):

Te falta cerrar el parantesis al final ")", por eso falla

Pero recomendaria que uses parametros

```
string connstring = "Data Source=Localhost;Initial Catalog=DevLiverpool_DB; Integrated Security = True";
SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(connstring);
cnn.Open();

string query = "insert into Ciudad_tb (Id_ciudaddestino, Ciudadestino) values (@Id, @ciudad)";
SqlCommand cmnd = new SqlCommand(query, cnn);

foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    cmnd.Parameters.Clear();
    cmnd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", Convert.ToInt32(row.ItemArray[0]));
    cmnd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ciudad", row.ItemArray[1].ToString()));
    cmnd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

de esta forma no tienes que instanciar el command en cada iteracion del foreach